# How disable the main form when I have a sub-from open

Tags: c#, winforms, monogame

I've been looking everywhere and I haven't found the code to disable the main form when sub form is open(I could be just wording it wrong. Just like when you're opening a file if you try click on the application the Open flashes and makes a sound.

How do I make the application disable while I'm in the second form that isn't the main?

Edit: So this is where place it since everyone is asking

```
        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        New_File newFile = new New_File();
        if (newFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
    }
```

Edit 2: Take 16 sec to open the file, and looks like:

Since you took all my rep I have to post a link http://puu.sh/aDBF4/9d7fd31926.png

I still don't understand why you guys are still downvoting me when I didn't what a ShowDialog was..

Comment: You didn't run into ShowDialog?

Comment: I have limited knowledge in C# trying to create something advance and out of my skill. So I didn't know. I through that ShowDialog only works with OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog.

Comment: It's the same sort of thing. When you open a `SaveFileDialog` window you cannot access anything outside that window until it has been closed.

Comment: Doesn't have much to do with "limited knowledge".  Just type your question title into Google and it gives you the answer.  Did you really "look everywhere" or was it just easier to ask somebody else to do it for you?

Comment: Actually it does. Since I didn't know what ShowFileDIalog did, and right now it still doesn't work. Like I said in my post "I could just wording it wrong."

Comment: Take while to load the form, and when I do, it deactivates the Ok, cancel, and browse... buttons. It remembers all the labels that I have in the form, but I could be placing it in wrong place. Also the X doesn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information, and please try to explain better than that, because I can't really understand your comment. Also, post the code that you're using to show your subform.

Comment: Try `newFile.ShowDialog(this)`.

Comment: @Howl not sure what you are doing, your code works for me. the creating form is disabled and just beeps when you click it when you use ShowDialog.

Comment: It's something within the form that making it not work. I just created a new form to try, and it works. (Within newFile form, not the entire form).

Comment: It just started to work for no reason...

Comment: Well, now I got fix the giant red X of death... which is going to be a pain to fix.

Comment: @Howl The big red X of death usually occurs when you try to access a UI element from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Why is this tagged monogame?

Comment: I'm using MonoGames to create a tile map editor. Which I need the components to do so. Plus MonoGames is a multiply platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to show the sub-form while the main form is visible but in disable mode, just follow the code below:

```
subForm.ShowDialog(); //Shows both main and sub form , but the main form is not accessible .
```

But if you want to have your main form hidden, follow this example :

```
this.Hide(); //Hides the main form.
subForm.ShowDialog(); //Shows the sub form.
this.Show(); //Shows the main form again after closing the sub form.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the 'Sub Form' use

```
form1.ShowDialog();
```

This will show the new form and you won't be able to access anything outside it until that form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the main form "own" the sub-form, and [modally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) show the sub-form.

- For WinForms: pass the `owner` to [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe(v=vs.110).aspx).
- For WPF: Set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) then call [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @downvoter: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**Winforms:**

```
new Form2().ShowDialog();
```

Shows a Dialog. Nothing more to say.

**A little neat trick:**

```
int num = (int)new Form2().ShowDialog();
```

It's pretty simple, the MainForm won't be access-able until you hit a button in Form2.