# How to come back to parent form without creating new instance of parent class in C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to come back to parent form without creating new instance of parent form in C# windows application?
I have tried this.Parent, this.MdiParent, this.MyParentForms but no one worked..

Comment: Do you open another form and after closing it you want back to your main form ? And what do you use ? WPF? winforms? Please clarify.

Comment: yes i am opening new form and after closing i want to come back to my main form and i am suing winforms

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable the main form when I have a sub-from open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109807/how-disable-the-main-form-when-i-have-a-sub-from-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a button in your parent form that is used to show another form. Add this code to the button's Click event:

```
//Click event of your button.
private void goToSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide(); //Hides the parent form.
   subform.ShowDialog(); //Shows the sub form.
   this.Show(); //Shows the parent form again, after closing the sub form.
}
```

Comment: May you show your codes, please? I always use this and it works!

Comment: yeah it is working..before that i was trying..

subform.Show() instead of subform.ShowDialog()

Answer (score -1):

In your child form, add a public property with type of your parent form :

```
public class ChildForm:From
{
   public ParentForm parent;
   //...
}
```

Then, in your click event of showing child form, do this :

```
private void goToSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Hide();
   ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
   child.parent = this;
   //other stuff
   child.Show();
}
```

At the end, in the FormClosing event of the child form, doing this :

```
private void Child_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
            this.parent.Show();
}
```

With this solution, if your parent form changes or updates, then you have the latest instance.

Comment: ParentForm comes under which namespace?

Comment: Same as the ChildForm namespace, or if their namespace is different from each other, you can using the namespace and go on.